# override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) Not been called

Tags: ios, swift, prepared-statement

I used RevealViewController in my project. I had given all the connections correctly for segue actions. But segue method not calling. I already used this in objective-c, its working fine. but why its not calling in swift.

Comment: Post your code and we know

Comment: I given segue links in Story Board. Here even the delegate method is not calling. I put break point at starting of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that all the connections are in storyboard and the delegate methods are not being called.

So the answer is simple and can be one of two options:

1- **The collection view has size zero.** In that situation the delegate methods are not being called for optimization reasons

2- **The delegate and/or the dataSource properties of the collection view are not attached to the view controller in storyboard.** You can check this in the connections pane

3- Another option that I cannot explain (happened to me once), relevant to swift only! **You're delegate methods are defined in the view controller not as extension.** I don't know why, but it did problems to me in the past. You (maybe) need to define your delegate methods as the following pseudo code:

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource implementation 
extension YourCollectionViewController {
    func yourDataSourceDelegeteMethod() { ... }
}
```

Do the same thing for your collection view delegate implementation